# maven multiproject structure with bom

Tags: java, maven, maven-bom

I have to refactor a Java monolithic application that uses Maven. The current application has a lot of dependencies (I mean, a lot. like 100-150 of them), many profiles and plugins. All of this will be modularized and and will be integrated into a GitLab pipeline, with a proper repository for artifacts.

I checked many examples for maven and boms.

So I was thinking about a structure like that:

```
project/BOM/pom.xml              //the only dependency manager for the whole project
project/pom.xml                  //this will be the root pom, and will import the BOM as a <dependency>, as the <parent> is reserved for the Enterprise management.
project/repo1/pom.xml          // this will import the project/pom as the parent.
project/repo1/node1/pom.xml    //this will use the dependencies imported by the BOM module
project/repo1/node2/pom.xml    //same
project/repo2/pom.xml          //same
...
etc.
```

Is this a "best practice" industrialized configuration or the bom should be embedded inside the main pom?

I know should split the depencencies between the repos, but the problem is that we have cross linked dependencies and at the time I cannot deal with them now. So I must centralize all of them as much as possible.